# How to make embed when field limit reached it will made a new field continuing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am currently making a lyrics command, and so some lyrics that requested characters are over 1024 which is the field limit. How can I make the embed when the field limit reached it will make a new field continuing?

My code:

````
    @commands.command()
    @commands.guild_only()
    async def lyrics(self, ctx, *, arg):
        data = requests.get(f"https://some-random-api.ml/lyrics?title={arg}").text
        try:
            jsontxt = json.loads(data)
            title = jsontxt["title"]
            author = jsontxt["author"]
            lyrics = jsontxt["lyrics"]
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send("<:information:773048990534991882> Sorry, I can't found the lyrics for the song you mentioned.")
            print("Error occured | "+str(e) + " | "+str(data))
        try:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title = f":musical_note: Lyrics | {title} | {author}",
                description = f"{lyrics}",
                timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
                colour = discord.Color.dark_blue()
            )
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(f"<:no:773048990727143464> Seems like an error has occurred: ```{e}```")
````

Thanks!

Comment: use description, it has 2048 chars limit

Comment: Some lyrics also have more than 2048+ characters.

Answer (score 0):

Check the lyrics length and if the lyric is longer than 2048, cut it

````py
    @commands.command()
    @commands.guild_only()
    async def lyrics(self, ctx, *, arg):
        data = requests.get(f"https://some-random-api.ml/lyrics?title={arg}").text
        try:
            jsontxt = json.loads(data)
            title = jsontxt["title"]
            author = jsontxt["author"]
            lyrics = jsontxt["lyrics"]
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send("<:information:773048990534991882> Sorry, I can't found the lyrics for the song you mentioned.")
            print("Error occured | "+str(e) + " | "+str(data))
        try:
            embed = discord.Embed(
                title = f":musical_note: Lyrics | {title} | {author}",
                description = lyrics if len(lyrics) <= 2048 else lyrics[:2048],
                timestamp=ctx.message.created_at,
                colour = discord.Color.dark_blue()
            )
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        except Exception as e:
            await ctx.send(f"<:no:773048990727143464> Seems like an error has occurred: ```{e}```")
````

Comment: How can I make it if reached 2048 chars it will create a new field for it?